# Not able to find out the reason behind a warning

Tags: java, eclipse, static, warnings

```
package morepackage;

public class Subclass extends Superclass {

public static void main (String args[])

{

Superclass t = new Subclass();

System.out.println(t.text);//warning is generated by this line

}

}
```

The **Superclass** contains an attribute **text** of **static type** which is initialized to the ***string "arpan"***

The code of the Superclass is given below:

```
package morepackage;

public class Superclass {

static String text = "arpan";

}
```

The code does not generate a compilation or run time error but eclipse given a **warning** on

the line "***System.out.println(t.text);***" saying that the **text** variable **should be

accessed in a static way** can anyone please explain why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's a static variable. You don't need an instance to use it, just do

```
System.out.println(Superclass.text)
```

Answer (score 3):

You defined `text` as a static variable

```
static String text = "arpan";
```

So the proper way to access it is to use

```
System.out.println(Superclass.text);
```